# Rails5 - best type for storing hours and minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What type should I assign to a variable to store opening and closing time of a place? Should it be datetime, time or just a simple string? Which one is easier to manage?

Comment: Is this for an ActiveRecord resource?

Comment: I am generating a model BusinessDay with name of the day, opening_from time and closing_at time. I would like to know what more experienced coders use as the variable type when generating such model.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have a datatype for representing Time of day. The Time datatype in Ruby is the number of seconds since Epoch (1970.01.01T00:00:00 UTC)

But you could represent `opening_hours` as the number of seconds since midnight.

Or you could simply define `opening_hours` as TimeWithZone (`datetime` in the migration), and then ignore the date part.

Comment: That is the kind of answer I was hoping to get! Thanks. Nice idea with number of seconds since midnight!

Answer (score 0):

The best one is to use `:time` because you want to store time, not date

Comment: Time.new is not a datatype.. `:datetime :timestamp :time` and `:date` are datatypes. You might be referring to the `:time` datatype